# S3 not preserving original time stamps of migrated data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm helping out with the IT department of an enterprise where they want to use File Gateway and Datasync to archive their existing data using S3. The team was successful in using Datasync to migrate the files into S3 but we have a problem now. I've looked around and i hear that S3 does not preserve the original timestamp of the files (if data was 5 years old on my file share, it will show the uploaded date instead of the original timestamp when we upload the data to S3). I found a robocopy command that does let us store on the S3 object the original time stamp (mtime metdata).

I'm not too technical so I may have some more questions but we're debating two ways.

1. Use datasync to migrate the data. then Use Lambda where whenever an object is uploaded it will take a look at the mtime metdata and upload the object to Glacier.. standard IA..etc. Can anyone please shed some light as to how they did it?
2. Use Lambda to tag the object then run the lifecycle policies (I assume on the CLI?) on the tag. but  the time stamp is in ns(unix)

It would be great if anyone can share their sample code or a different work around on this.

Comment: It is not possible to modify the "Last-Modified" meta data on an S3 Object (see [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html) for what you can and can't set).  However, you can store arbitrary key/value pairs on the object and perhaps this is what robocopy is doing.  But if you go to the S3 console you'll see that the Last-Modified date is still the same.

Comment: yes, so what is the work around on this? We don't want to touch the last-modified date but we do want to move our old data into glacier but seems like the life cycle policies only opearte based on last-modified date?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this I would split the problem in two.  The first part is copying existing, older data to the appropriate storage class.  So, in Unix shell, something as simple as:

```
find . -mtime +365 -exec aws s3 cp --storage-class GLACIER {} s3://yourBucketName \;
```

will copy all files older than 365 days directly to Glacier.  Your business rules will dictate the age of files that go to a particular storage class.

Next, once you've copied all of the files to the appropriate storage class setup something like DataSync to maintain the files.  You'll still want S3 life cycle policies on S3 so that the appropriate files will be pushed to cheaper storage classes over time.  If you have an old but frequently accessed file in S3 add one or more tags so that you can use that in your filter to not push the file to, for example, Glacier.

Comment: Hello, what is the find . -type doing and is the mtime pulling from the metadata? I tried this on the cli and the error is asking for paths..

Comment: @ownaadz - the `find` I show is a Unix command though it exists on Windows too with a very different syntax.  Basically what I showed as an example says "starting in the current directory (the "dot" in the command) look for files (--type f) that have a modification time 365 days or more in the past".  In retrospect, you may not want just files but directories too.  That was meant as an example and, of course, your use case may be different.  I'll updated the post with what is likely a bit better code.

Comment: I dont think this is evaluating based on the metadata we tagged with robocopy which is stored under x-amz-meta-file-mtime? Is the mtime just looking at the last modification date?